# flash to html5 conversion with com folder

Tags: html, flash, createjs, google-swiffy

I am converting my flash files to HTML 5 ,I have tried using **swiffy** and **createjs** in Adobe but no luck as it work's only with smaller swf's and I have **com** folder.so any software/tricks available on how I can convert such swf's files

Comment: You can't convert Flash with CreateJS and maintain interactivity, code, etc. It is more a workflow to create HTML5 content using Adobe Flash/Animate.

Comment: @Lanny yes ok thnx for the info